# Change project icon in Solution-Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2017, project-template

I recently created a template from a CSharp WebApi project and would like to have the icon from this template also displayed in the Solution-Explorer.

When using the template export wizard of visual studio I supplied the custom icon I want for that, but this icon is only shown in the create-a-new-project wizard:

[image: Icon used in the create a new project wizard]

I would also like it to be seen here, but theres still the Icon of a CSharp Web-Api-Project:

[image: Icon used in the solution explorer]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple answer to this question, which actually makes sense:

You can't change this in a meaningful and easy way.

That's because this icon comes from the installed project types, not the templates which are selected while creating a new project.

If it would be set by the template, that would require the icon to be stored with the project even though it has not to do anything with the project output. If it wouldn't be stored with the project, the users which open this project in visual studio would be required to have the template installed which this project was created from.